# row-column if-else using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
stats_all_score.head()

class   score1  score2  score3
A       1.67    3.60    5.50
A       3.60    3.25    2.10
A       2.25    3.25    3.25
B       1.17    6.50    21.00
C       3.20    3.25    2.30
..      ..      ..      ..
```

how can I make stats_all_score like this, where if class=A it will make the other columns 0 except score1, if class=B, will make others 0 except score 2 and if class=C, will make others 0 except score3:

```
class   score1  score2  score3
A       1.67    0       0
A       3.60    0       0
A       2.25    0       0
B       0       6.50    0
C       0       0       2.30
..      ..      ..      ..
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) for compare column `Class` with columns, which are mapped by `dict`. Then change mask by setting `True`s to mask for column `class` by [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) by position and last create new `df`  by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
#dynamically create dict, thanks Bharath shetty
d = dict(zip(df.columns[1:],df.set_index('class').index.unique()))
#same as
#d = {'score1':'A','score2':'B','score3':'C'}

m = df['class'].values[:, None] == df.columns.to_series().map(d).values
m[:, df.columns.get_loc('class')] = True
#same as set first column to 0
#m[:, 0] = True
print (m)
[[ True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False]
 [ True False  True False]
 [ True False False  True]]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, df.values, 0), index = df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
  class score1 score2 score3
0     A   1.67      0      0
1     A    3.6      0      0
2     A   2.25      0      0
3     B      0    6.5      0
4     C      0      0    2.3
```

Comment: what if my data is around 2000+ rows :(

Comment: I think it should be very fast.

Comment: @Bharathshetty - yes, it is another possible solution

Comment: df columns should be 'score1 ... na. Though this restricts me think of another solution.

Comment: can u post it? =)